# Uninstalling the program Padre

Tags: uninstall

After uninstalling the program Padre (Rentas 2014)

In two folders installed applications blank as not remove stayed.

Can someone help me please?

My operating system is Ubuntu 14.04LTS.

Thank you, Sincerely, Marnix

Comment: Which folders do you mean?

Comment: How did you install the program? This information is essential to know, how to remove it.

Comment: I used the steps explained by de provider himself (the Spanish Gubernamental department)

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution myself: in Ubuntu Software Center, I found a program, called "Find File/Folders". I found those two leftovers and deleted them using that program. At first, deleting does not make them disappear from the list, but after restarting "Find File/Folders" the files were really deleted. Thank you very much for your help.